# Pepper robot engage and animations

Tags: pepper

When Pepper's robot ability to engage human is taken over with appropriate function...

```
     EngageHuman engage = humanAwareness.makeEngageHuman(qiContext.getRobotContext(), human);
     engage.addOnHumanIsEngagedListener(() -> {...}
     engage.addOnHumanIsDisengagingListener(() -> {...}
     Future engAction = engage.async().run;
```

Every **animation** that is launched during this time, when Pepper robot is engaged by this way ( Not the basic way if we don't override engage ) **Can't be launched.**

For example, we have chat bookmarks that start animations, while robot is engaged, non of the animations play.

Is this an API limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you engaged someone, the motors of the neck are used to track this person.

So it is not possible to start an animation that contains some head movements.

If you deactivate the head movements of the animation it will work.

Comment: Hey, Thomas, what I have just tested again, but now with trajectories. When Pepper is engaged with someone and you call to e.x. turn around trajectory or move base to the left, it throws QiException. From what I have seen, you cannot disable head movements in trajectories. How to work around this problem?

Comment: Hello, Unfortunately it is not possible to use trajectories while someone is engaged and there is no workaround.